# Faster way to merge multiple files

Tags: linux, file, bash

I have multiple small files in Linux (about 70,000 files) and I want to add a word to the end of each line of the files and then merge them all into a single file.

I'm using this script:

```
for fn in *.sms.txt 
do 
    sed 's/$/'$fn'/' $fn >> sms.txt
    rm -f $fn
done
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Yes, if you are okay with writing some Java or C++ code, you could parallelize this code.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan: You're probably right, but once (a year or so ago) I ran a complex `gsed` filter over a few million files (a total of 60 GBs) that converted them from an xml-like format to a json-like (not quite though, but the important thing is that it was much much more complex than what this question needs) and it took about 2 hours to finish. Granted, it was an 8-core machine with 15000 RPM HDD, but still, ridiculously faster than I could've hoped. (and note that I said `gsed`, not `sed`. OS X's `sed` was more than two orders of magnitude slower).

Comment: Obviously, my comment above assumes that you don't need to run this query more than once (i.e., it's like "cleaning" the data before feeding it to a database for storage or mining).

Answer (score 6):

I tried with these files:

```
for ((i=1;i<70000;++i)); do printf -v fn 'file%.5d.sms.txt' $i; echo -e "HAHA\nLOL\nBye" > "$fn"; done
```

I tried your solution that took about **4 minutes** (real) to process. The problem with your solution is that you're forking on `sed` 70000 times! And forking is rather slow.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="sms.txt"

# Create file "$filename" or empty it if it already existed
> "$filename"

# Start editing with ed, the standard text editor
ed -s "$filename" < <(
   # Go into insert mode:
   echo i
   # Loop through files
   for fn in *.sms.txt; do
      # Loop through lines of file "$fn"
      while read l; do
         # Insert line "$l" with "$fn" appended to
         echo "$l$fn"
      done < "$fn"
   done
   # Tell ed to quit insert mode (.), to save (w) and quit (q)
   echo -e ".\nwq"
)
```

This solution took ca. **6 seconds**.

Don't forget, `ed` is the standard text editor, and don't overlook it! If you enjoyed `ed`, you'll probably also enjoy `ex`!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Almost Same as gniourf_gniourf's solution, but without ed:

```
for i in *.sms.txt 
do   
   while read line   
   do    
     echo $line $i
   done < $i
done >sms.txt
```

Comment: Nice one! (would be better with a few quotes here and there, though). `ed` seems to be faster: Your solution took 7 seconds! But a big +1 for a 100% bash solution.

Answer (score 2):

What, no love for `awk`?

```
awk '{print $0" "FILENAME}' *.sms.txt >sms.txt
```

Using `gawk`, this took **1-2 seconds** on gniourf_gniourf's [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13330805/1743811) on my machine (according to `time`).

`mawk` is about 0.2 seconds faster than `gawk` here.

Answer (score 1):

This perl script adds the actual filename at the end of each line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
while(<>){
    chomp;
    print $_, $ARGV, "\n";
}
```

Call it like this:

```
scriptname *.sms.txt > sms.txt
```

Since there is only one process and no regular expression processing involved it should be quite fast.